# How do I group input elements of the same class that are sibling of a parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

The rendered html in my cshtml file.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <input class="Question" datafield="1" type="text" />  //question 1
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="Question" datafield="2" type="checkbox" />//question 2
        <input class="Question" datafield="2" type="text" />     //question 2
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="Question" datafield="3" type="radio" />   //question 3
        <input class="Question" datafield="3" type="radio" />   //question 3
        <input class="Question" datafield="3" type="radio" />   //question 3
    </div>
    <div>
        <select datafield="4" class="Question">                 //question 4
        <option val='sample1'>text1</option>   
        <option val='sample2'>text2</option>   
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason I am using class is because there is a varying number of questions as I am looping through questions stored in the database.  The thing is some questions have multiple answer and some questions are single line answers.

I want to be able to be able to group these element's value as answers to their respective questions. I have manage to add a `datafield` property to distinguish one group from another.

Currently I have this in my javascript:

```
var question = [];
var questions = $('.Question');
$.each(questions, function (i, element) {
});
```

The problem is that I can't think of an if condition in the `$.each` to group the elements into the arrays.

Desired output:

```
var x = [datafield1:{input elements with datafield=1}, datafield2:{input elements with datafield=2}, datafield3:{input elements with datafield=3}, datafield4:{input elements with datafield=4}, .. ]
```

hopefully an array which I could loop through for validation.

```
for(...)
{
    for()
    {
        if(x[.][.]=='' || undefined)
        return false;
    }
}
```

*Note*:
the number of question varies

Comment: > that are sibling of a parent div ... how does that work?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking here. Can you re-write the question to clearly show the starting code that you have, the problem you're trying to solve, and the output you're trying to achieve

Comment: Agreed with @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Let me edit it for a sec. I will be adding a desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's maintain the field value in the elements in a proper `data` attribute.

```
<input class="Question" data-field="1" type="text" />  //question 1
```

You can then do this in your for-loop, adding properties with a name that can be traced back to your question ids to an object (here named `groupedData`) :

```js
var groupedData = {};
 
var questions = $('.Question');

$.each(questions, function (i, elem) {
   var questionId = $(elem).data("field");
   if(!groupedData.hasOwnProperty(questionId))
      groupedData[questionId] = [];

   groupedData[questionId].push($(elem).val()); //or whatever information you want to keep per-question.

});

console.log(groupedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
        <input class="Question" data-field="1" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="Question" data-field="2" type="checkbox" />
        <input class="Question" data-field="2" type="text" />     
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="Question" data-field="3" type="radio" />
        <input class="Question" data-field="3" type="radio" />
        <input class="Question" data-field="3" type="radio" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <select data-field="4" class="Question">
          <option val='sample1'>text1</option>   
          <option val='sample2'>text2</option>   
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: keep in mind that you will need to do some special casing for the checkboxes / dropdown lists

Comment: Trying this one out.  Accepting this after it works.

Comment: Worked! Good stuff @Timothy

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the list of *questions* and their *answers* - see demo below:

```js
var questions = Array.prototype.reduce.call($('.Question'), function(p,c) {
  let key = 'datafield ' + $(c).attr('datafield');
  p[key] = p[key] || [];
  p[key].push($(c).val());
  return p;
},Object.create(null));

console.log(questions);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <input class="Question" datafield="1" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="Question" datafield="2" type="checkbox"/>
    <input class="Question" datafield="2" type="text" /> 
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="Question" datafield="3" type="radio" /> 
    <input class="Question" datafield="3" type="radio" /> 
    <input class="Question" datafield="3" type="radio" /> 
  </div>
  <div>
    <select datafield="4" class="Question">               
        <option val='sample1'>text1</option>   
        <option val='sample2'>text2</option>   
        </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: neat and clean, but keep in mind that some older browsers do *not* support  `Array.prototype.reduce`

Answer (score 0):

Set each `data-field` property as the object key:

```js
var output = {};

$('.Question[data-field]').each(function() {
    var prop = $(this).data('field');
    if (typeof output[prop] === "undefined") {
      output[prop] = [];
    }
    output[prop].push($(this).val());
});

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <input class="Question" data-field="1" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="Question" data-field="2" type="checkbox" />
    <input class="Question" data-field="2" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="Question" data-field="3" type="radio" />
    <input class="Question" data-field="3" type="radio" />
    <input class="Question" data-field="3" type="radio" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <select data-field="4" class="Question">
          <option val='sample1'>text1</option>   
          <option val='sample2'>text2</option>   
        </select>
  </div>
</div>
```